# capturing value of parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I really need your help on this guys I am stuck and not sure where to start the fix. So i have this form where the user can select a case and parties. I am supposed save and pass along the values of the selected items. I was able to save the case selections but i am having trouble saving the selected party. Here is my code snippets regarding gathering data and saving them.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(VisitViewModel viewModel, Guid[] associatedCasesSelected, Guid[] selectedParties)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            viewModel.Time = _timeEntryHelper.Value;
            AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        var visitEntry = Mapper.Map<VisitViewModel, VisitEntry>(viewModel);
        visitEntry.VisitDate = _timeEntryHelper.AddTimeToDate(visitEntry.VisitDate);
        visitEntry.UserId = _currentUser.UserId;
        visitEntry.OfficeId = _currentUser.OfficeId;
        try
        {
            _visitEntryService.Create(visitEntry, associatedCasesSelected, selectedParties);
            this.FlashInfo(string.Format(Message.ConfirmationMessageCreate, Resources.Entities.Visit.EntityName));
        }
        catch (RulesException ex)
        {
            ex.CopyTo(ModelState);
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Case", new { caseId = viewModel.CaseId });
        AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**VisitEntryService:**

```
public void Create(VisitEntry visitEntry,IList<Guid>caseIds, IList<Guid>partyIds )
    {
        EnsureValid(visitEntry);
        _visitEntryRepository.Save(visitEntry);
        caseIds = AddCurrentCaseToCases(visitEntry.CaseId, caseIds,partyIds);
        foreach (var caseId in caseIds.Distinct())
        {
            var visit = new Visit {CaseId = caseId, VisitEntryId = visitEntry.VisitEntryId};
            _visitService.Create(visit);
        }
    }
```

**VisitEntryRepository:**

```
 public void Save(VisitEntry visitEntry)
    {
        if (visitEntry.VisitEntryId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            visitEntry.VisitEntryId = Guid.NewGuid();
            visitEntry.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            DataContext.VisitEntries.InsertOnSubmit(visitEntry);
        }
        else
        {
            var currentVisitEntry = Get(visitEntry.VisitEntryId);
            if (currentVisitEntry == null) throw RepositoryExceptionFactory.Create("VisitEntry", "VisitEntryId");
            currentVisitEntry.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
            currentVisitEntry.VisitDate = visitEntry.VisitDate;
            currentVisitEntry.VisitType =
                DataContext.VisitTypes.SingleOrDefault(vt => vt.VisitTypeId == visitEntry.VisitTypeId);
            currentVisitEntry.Note = visitEntry.Note;
        }
        DataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

I am not sure how to get this to save the selected party as it is saving the case information and selected case. Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The save call is a bit earlier so your changes made after your fire SubmitChanges, move the SubmitChanges to the end you should good to go I believe

**UPDATE**

what I mean is change code like following and see if that helps

**CONTROLLER:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(VisitViewModel viewModel, Guid[] associatedCasesSelected, Guid[] selectedParties)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        viewModel.Time = _timeEntryHelper.Value;
        AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    var visitEntry = Mapper.Map<VisitViewModel, VisitEntry>(viewModel);
    visitEntry.VisitDate = _timeEntryHelper.AddTimeToDate(visitEntry.VisitDate);
    visitEntry.UserId = _currentUser.UserId;
    visitEntry.OfficeId = _currentUser.OfficeId;
    try
    {
        _visitEntryService.Create(visitEntry, associatedCasesSelected, selectedParties);
        this.FlashInfo(string.Format(Message.ConfirmationMessageCreate, Resources.Entities.Visit.EntityName));
        DataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (RulesException ex)
    {
        ex.CopyTo(ModelState);
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Case", new { caseId = viewModel.CaseId });
    AddLookupsToViewModel(viewModel);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**VisitEntryRepository:**

```
public void Save(VisitEntry visitEntry)
{
    if (visitEntry.VisitEntryId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        visitEntry.VisitEntryId = Guid.NewGuid();
        visitEntry.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        DataContext.VisitEntries.InsertOnSubmit(visitEntry);
    }
    else
    {
        var currentVisitEntry = Get(visitEntry.VisitEntryId);
        if (currentVisitEntry == null) throw RepositoryExceptionFactory.Create("VisitEntry", "VisitEntryId");
        currentVisitEntry.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
        currentVisitEntry.VisitDate = visitEntry.VisitDate;
        currentVisitEntry.VisitType =
            DataContext.VisitTypes.SingleOrDefault(vt => vt.VisitTypeId == visitEntry.VisitTypeId);
        currentVisitEntry.Note = visitEntry.Note;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it. But from my testing i am passing in case info along with cases and parties. the case info and cases are saved but the parties info are not being saved not sure how to pass them to ensure that they are saved.

Comment: Only call SubmitChanges once so you make it like a transaction, here your code seems could call SubmitChanges multiple times that why some saved some not, if you make it transactional, you get data integrity so they either all saved or none.

Comment: sadly it didn't work - still the parties are not being saved.

Comment: how did you change it, it sounds like a debugging should find where the problem is

Comment: I only called the .SubmitChanges and removed the upper insert on submit - got an error and then i moved the insertOnSubmit all the way down before the .SubmitChanges and didn't get a change once running it. when i debug it doesn't show that it is capturing the partyId to start with

Comment: No need to move InsertOnSubmit and it need to be there, just change SubmitChanges, I've updated my answer with code changes, please check if that works

Comment: I just tried it with updated code but in the controller it is not letting me add DataContext.SubmitChanges()

Comment: in VisitEntryService do you think 'var visit = new Visit {CaseId = caseId, VisitEntryId = visitEntry.VisitEntryId};' needs to include something regarding party info? because it should hold information regarding parties before passing it to the visitRepository for saving.

Comment: I thought your Visit is party, sorry not sure what the relationship between your data, btw you said  it is not letting me add DataContext.SubmitChanges() then what's the error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17846/discussion-between-simon-wang-and-amina)